# jQuery Mobile - base URL without "/index.html" and offline access

Tags: jquery-mobile, url-routing, offline

How to get access to app in offline mode using just base domain URL, for example http://somedomain.com/

When i'm online everything is ok, server redirects it to index.html automatically. Problem is that in cache manifest provided only exact file "index.html", so in offline mode i can only get access to http://somedomain.com/index.html, it's cached and exist, but not as http://somedomain.com/, because server is not available and i even can't do javascript redirect, coz there is no entrance file.

Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the FALLBACK section in your Manifest file - that will redirect ANY requests while offline to a certain file, e.g:

FALLBACK:
   / /index.html

Some [more details](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Hope this helps...

PS: Please mark as Answer if this worked out for you!